# Binary-like search

Tags: python, algorithm, search

It's theoretical question.

[exercise from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/) as basis.

My solution for task is binary search. But question is not about it.

I found perfect [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/discuss/1681129/32ms-4-line-Python-solution-faster-than-90.36-submissions) on Discuss tab.

(next code has been taken from there)

```
class Solution:
    def mySqrt(self, x: int) -> int:
        low, high= 1, x
        while low<high:
            high = (low + high) // 2
            low = x // high

        return high
```

It works perfect. My question is:

For regular binary search we take middle of sequence and depending of comparison result remove excessive part (left or right) next repeat till result.

**What is this implementation based on?**

This solution cut part of sequence right after middle and small part from start.

Comment: This method is specific to the computation of the square root. When low and high converge, low.high = low² = high² = x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code isn't based on binary search. It's based instead on adapting the ancient "[Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)" to integer arithmetic. That in turn can be viewed as anticipating an instance of Newton's more-general method for finding a root of an equation.

Keeping distinct `low` and `high` variables isn't important in this code. For example, it's more commonly coded along these lines:

```
def intsqrt(n):
    guess = n  # must be >= true floor(sqrt(n))
    while True:
        newguess = (guess + (n // guess)) // 2
        if guess <= newguess:
            return guess
        guess = newguess
```

but with more care taken to find a better initial guess.

BTW, binary search increases the number of "good bits" by 1 per iteration. This method approximately *doubles* the number of "good bits" per iteration, so is much more efficient the closer the guess gets to the final result.

Answer (score 2):

This method is subtle, though was known of the Babylonians (see Tim's answer).

Assume that `h > √x`. Then

1. `l = x/h < √x` and
2. `(l+h)/2 > √x`.

The first property is obvious. For the second, observe that 1. and 2. imply
`x+h² > 2h√x` or `(h-√x)^2 > 0`, which is true.

So `h` remains above `√x`, but it gets closer and closer (because `(l+h)/2 < h`). And when the computation is made with integers, there is a moment such that `l≥h`.

---

How was this method discovered ?

Assume that you have an approximation `h` of `√x` and we want to improve it, with a correction `δ`. We write `x = (h-δ)² = h²-2hδ + δ² = x`. If we neglect `δ²`, then we draw `h-δ = (h²+x)/2h = (h+x/h)/2`, which is our `(h+l)/2`.

Comment: It's actually even subtler than that ;-) For example, pass 99. `low` and `high` never become equal. In the penultimate iteration, `high` becomes 10 and `low` 9. So it goes one more time, leaving `high` 9 and `low` 11. Then it's done, and returns `high` (9). Proof of convergence - even termination - when using integer arithmetic requires careful analysis of floor function properties.

Comment: @TimPeters: you are right, I didn't check if crossing was possible. thanks for raising this.